# My strings won't compare to symbols

Tags: string

I'm trying to check in a string has any symbols in it (;:,'".!) and delete it here's the too methods I've tried.

```
for (int i = 0; i<possidrome.length(); i++)
    {
        if (possidrome.find_first_of(",;:",i) != string::npos)
        {
            possidrome.erase(i, 1);
        }
```

and the char.at compareison

```
for (int i = 0; i<possidrome.length(); i++)
    {
        if (possidrome.at(i) == ":;!.,'")
        {
            possidrome.erase(i, 1);
        }
```

the first method deletes the wrong letters and the second won't allow me to compare i in the string to check if it's a symbol, I'm sure it's an easy fix but it's been a pain in the butt for hours so thanks if anyone can help.

Comment: What programming language is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the language to be C++. Here's a bit of code that should do the trick:

```
// your input string here
std::string str = "AAh! ah, aaaa... AHa!?";

// the string of all characters to remove
const std::string symbols = "!,.?";

// remove all instances using lambda predicate
str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [&](const char& ch){
    return symbols.find(ch) != std::string::npos;
}), str.end());

// str now has all characters in symbols removed
// ie str == "AAh ah aaa AHa"
```

Hope that helps!